# How is System Background Colour handled by iOS versions that don't support the light mode / dark mode?

Tags: ios, darkmode, lightmode

I'm setting up my app so that the UI (mostly in storyboard) uses the default background color / default label color, so that it auto adjusts for dark or light mode.

What happens if the iOS doesn't support light mode / dark mode - does it default to black on white?

Comment: Do you really need to support iOS 12? Do you have a device with iOS 12 to test your app?

Comment: No older device/iOS to hand unfortunately, I guess I don't need to support that far back. Is there ever a case where -Default (System Background Color)- would ever be unavailable in iOS 13 onwards?

Comment: Any device running iOS 13 or later fully supports dark/light mode and all of the dynamic colors like systemBackgroundColor. Supporting iOS 12 for a new app at this point is too much work for no gain. iOS 13 also added SF Symbols and support for scenes. Supporting iOS 12 means lots of extra code and images to deal with those missing features.

Comment: I'll stick with iOS 13+ then. Thanks for your help.